# How to partition a Azure SQL server table and repartition automatically?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am learning Data Engineering on Azure.
While learning about Azure SQL server, while learning about partitioning,
I saw that partitioning SQL Server table is very different from other like in Bigquery or in Oracle.

Can anyone explain me how to create a partition table in Azure SQL Server.
And , once the range for partition is reached,how we can automatically add new range in partition?

For example, if table is partitioned on Column Order_Year, and currently have values from 2015-2020.
If I got a new value for that column, like 2021, how we can automatically add that partition to partition range?

Comment: In general (for SQL Server, not sure about Synapse) you would just pad the partition function with a few extra years at creation time and make sure you have something scheduled to split it in plenty of time before it runs out. Is kind of annoying there isn't something better as I have seen the aftermath when this scheduled job on some legacy DB has failed and everything has been added into the end partition for years before anyone noticed!

Comment: As @MartinSmith said, there isn't a declarative way tot add partitions dynamically. Add the DDL for your existing partition function to your question and I'll provide an answer with a script that can be scheduled add partitions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The table partitioning separates the huge logical tables into numerous smaller logical tables. Better data administration is made possible by these smaller tables, which also eliminate the need for distinct tables.

To create partition table you should use partiotion function and partition scheme.

**Partition function:** The boundary of each division is determined by the partitioning function.

Define partiotion function with range

```
CREATE  PARTITION  FUNCTION pf_OrderYear (INT)
AS  RANGE  RIGHT  FOR  VALUES (2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020);
```

[image]

**Partition Scheme**: Table partitions are mapped to various filegroups using the partitioning technique.

Create partition scheme

```
CREATE  PARTITION  SCHEME ps_OrderYear
AS  PARTITION pf_OrderYear
ALL  TO ('PRIMARY') ;
```

[image]

Create table with `create table` command with the partition scheme specified.

```
CREATE  TABLE PartitionedTable
(
   ID INT,
  Order_Year INT
)
ON ps_OrderYear(Order_Year);
```

[image]

To add new range you can use alter partition function with **Split Range** as per below code:

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pf_OrderYear()
SPLIT RANGE (2021);
```

[image]

For more information you can refer this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/modify-a-partition-function?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it just shows how to create partitions. Essentially, it's the documentation tutorials without the explanations. Run in a SQL Notebook

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Added detail explanations of execution and reference link for the same.